# if you had to choose a planet to colonise with humans, what planet would it be and why?

Tags: colonization

within our solor system or beyond, what planet is most like Earth that humans could possibly colonise?  Assuming our ability to travel there was safe and when we arrived we could reproduce.

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange, science student!  Unfortunately, our rules do not support poll-based questions.  Their format is not conducive to the stack exchange Q&A format.  You could phrase similar questions, thought.  For example, you might be able to ask which planet has the best thermal conditions (in terms of incident solar radiation, geothermal energy, and insulative capacity) to support a colony of humans.  Such a question would have an answer that we could all agree upon using StackExchange's voting scheme.

Comment: @CortAmmon Maybe not so off topic : http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2507/where-in-the-solar-system-is-the-most-viable-place-to-put-my-colonists-after-ma

Comment: If I may suggest an edit, we specify it's outside of the Solar system? The closest possible candidate(s) for colonization.

Comment: Either inside our solar system or out.  Inside I would suggest Mars for its water store, but there is no soil which would limit natural resources for human life like plant growth.  Interested to hear your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

I'd colonise earth, because it is already populated with natives that I could enslave.